# How to determine Crystal reports usage

Tags: logging, crystalreports

I've recently undergone training in SQL reporting services with the idea being that I would be leading our conversion from Crystal reports (Enterprise 10) to SQL Reporting services.  There are 103 Crystal reports on our system however few of us are aware of the usage of these reports, almost all of them except a couple predate our current IT personal.  A handful we know are used by everybody, a chunk we are sure aren't used and the rest we have no idea, some might only get used once a month, others daily by only one person in the organization.

Ideally I would like to find a way to see the hit counts on some of these reports.  I already attempted to look at the IIS logs using LogParser but realized that the individual reports aren't stored as separate files but as a single page that generates the report so I have one page with a few thousand hits.  I also looked at the administrative console of crystal however the last run field is completely out of whack, many reports have it as either an odd date or blank and these are reports I helped a user run yesterday so I can't consider it as reliable.

Is there a way or a particular log location of some kind that could show me how often a report is accessed over some period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a while since I've touched Crystal Enterprise (and then, I was using Crystal Analysis Pro rather than Crystal Reports), but from what I remember, the "info object id" is on the URL to the csp page that represents the viewer - you could see if they're in your logs? each info object id represents a single report (or saved view) - with a little effort and poking around with the COM libraries that get installed when you install the CE addons to CR, you can actually pull back the actual report file from the CE infostore.

**EDIT:**
Thinking about it, you could modify the CSP page to add some logging code -- they're effectively ASP pages with a few extra bells and whistles. The CSP pages did get compiled into CWRs, but I forget if that was CE11 or 10...

Comment: That actually looks like it might be a very good lead, completely overlooked that particular parameter in all the log spam.  Should be trivial now to obtain the report IDs, at the very least I can manually access a report and then relook at the log to see what was hit.  Using logparser to push the results into excel then I should be able to extract what I need using some built in functions there.

Comment: It works, had to adjust my query a bunch then use RIGHT(LEFT()) functions in excel in the outputted CSV to extract the objid into a column which I could then sort and subtotal.  In crystal Reports management console each report is listed as frs://Input/a_171/062/000/16043/6e83dd0803fd628.rpt and the 16043 matches one of the extracted IDs for my heaviest used report and was about what I expected.  Now to get all the ids and then convert only what is needed.